# Rotation of triangles using collection of lines

Tags: java, rotation

I am kinda stuck in trying to rotate a triangle figure.

So I am trying to rotate an entire triangle which is made up of Lines. I have two classes, one Line class which creates a single Line. And a Triangle class which creates all the triangles by combining all the lines. First, below is my Line class which implements an interface called Curve. Curve contains definitions for draw, rotate, translate etc. Please note that it I have only added the relevant functions for my question. So in my rotate function the end point of Line in question (X2,Y2) are rotated. I am not sure if the formula is correctly implemented

```
public class Line implements Curve {

    double x1Point;
    double y1Point;
    double x2Point;
    double y2Point;

    public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        this.x1Point = x1;
        this.y1Point = y1;
        this.x2Point = x2;
        this.y2Point = y2;
    }
    public void rotate(double degrees) {
        x2Point = ((double)(x1Point * Math.cos(degrees * (Math.PI / 180)))) - ((double)(y1Point * Math.sin(degrees  * (Math.PI / 180))));
        y2Point = ((double)(x1Point * Math.cos(degrees * (Math.PI / 180)))) + ((double)(y1Point * Math.sin(degrees  * (Math.PI / 180))));   
    }
```

Then in my Triangle class which also implements a curve class, I add all the lines to my global arraylist and rotate all of them in my rotate function. Please note that the curves are drawn properly on the screen. I have not added the draw method as it is not relevant to my question

```
public class Triangle implements Curve  {

    ArrayList<Curve> list = new ArrayList<Curve>();

    public void add(Line line){
        list.add(line);
    }

     public void rotate(double degrees) {
        for(Curve c: list){
           c.rotate(degrees);
        }
    }
```

So my rotation of Triangle is not proper. I am not sure where the problem lies. It could be in the formula to rotate individual lines but I am not sure. Hope someone can provide valuable feedback!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to rotate the triangle around its center (default rotation is applied around *origin `(0, 0)`*), so you need to translate to origin first, then apply rotation and finally translate back to the original position.

Here is some code, so you get the idea. Let's say you have the point (vertex of triangle) `p1` and `center_triangle` is the center of the triangle.

```
//TRANSLATE TO ORIGIN
double x1 = p1.getX() - center_triangle.x;
double y1 = p1.getY() - center_triangle.y;

//APPLY ROTATION
x1 = x1 * Math.cos(angle) - y1 * Math.sin(angle));
y1 = x1 * Math.sin(angle) + y1 * Math.cos(angle));

//TRANSLATE BACK
p1.setLocation(x1 + center.x, y1 + center.y);
```

You must do this for each point of the triangle.

**Note:**

Use `Math.toRadians(degrees)` instead of `degrees * (Math.PI / 180)`.

Comment: Shouldn't I be translating each Line to the origin? So it would be ideal to change the rotate function inside my Line class to translate to origin, rotate and then translate back but then I don't know the center of the triangle.

Comment: Do this in `Triangle` class.